# Могу ли я ссылаться на члены класса перед вызовом нетривиального конструктора?

Tags: c++, c++11

Читая c++ 11 стандарт (ревизию N3242) я наткнулся на следующее утверждение:

> (12.7 Construction and destruction). For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undeﬁned behavior.

То есть насколько я понимаю, следующий код конструктора `Foo` содержит неопределенное поведение (в месте инициализации `i`)?

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct Foo
{
    A a;
    int i;
    Foo() : a(), i(a.i)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Вообще порядок создания членов класса определён, по порядку объявления. Т.е. код не должен содержать неопределённого поведения. Правда небходимо разобраться что имели ввиду авторы в 12.7

Comment: @free_ze, тут связь не с базовым классом, а с использованием `non-static member`

Comment: @Unick, согласен, я всегда учитывал при написании кода, порядок обьявления членов класса. Просто это утверждение из стандарта выбило меня с толку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажеся код верный, т.к. A a; уже инициализирована в момент инициализации int i;. В следующий код бы имел неопределёное поведение:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct Foo
{
    int i;
    A a;
    Foo() : a(), i(a.i)
    {}
};
```

Т.к. i создавалась бы раньеш чем A a;. Насколько я знаю члены класса инициализируются в порядки объявления в класса.

Comment: порядок инициализации членов класса строго определен стандартом.

Comment: Про порядок вопросов нет. Меня сбило с толку понятие `reffering non static member`

Comment: Мне кажется это оно и есть. "referring to any non-static member" имеется ввиду члены класса, конструктор которого вызываеться.

Comment: @Unick, кстати да. Тогда это утверждение можно понять (использование членов класса, у которых не был вызван конструктор) - правда в стандарте по-другому немного написано